# How does Postgres know which logs have been archived?

Tags: postgresql, rdbms, postgresql-9.2, archive

I'm asking this because Postgres was hard-stopped yesterday, and I fear that there could be partial / corrupt data in one of my archived log segments. I'd like to simply delete the logs from my slave server and just have Postgres start again from the beginning (there are only about 90 segments, so it won't take long), but I'm not sure what to do, to get Postgres to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On master there is archive_status directory in pg_xlog which contains files that mark status of archiving of xlogs.

Comment: FWIW, I did delete all the archives from my slave, then deleted all the `.done` files from my master's `archive_status` directory while the server was off. When I restarted the server the archive process started like normal, but no archiving is taking place (over 40 min, and no archives have been moved - `rsync` hasn't been used once). Fortunately, I'm only using this environment to learn in, but I'd be interested to know what happened when I deleted the archive status files and started the server again.